# How to save an image from json response with PHP

Tags: php, html, css, json, image

I have used an API to get an image of something and the image isn't in the format of a URL? How would I go about saving it to an image file (.jpeg)

```
"screenshot": {
"data": "_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj_2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj_wAARCADwAUADASIAAhEBAxEB_8QAHAABAAIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMFAQQGAgcI_8QAOxAAAQMCAgcFBwQBAwUAAAAAAAECAwQRBRIGExQhMVFSQVSRk9EHIjJhcYHSFaGi8EIXI-EzgrHB8f_EABoBAQADAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAACBAUDAQb_xAAtEQEAAQMCBAUDBAMAAAAAAAAAAQIDEQQhEjFRUhNBYXGBBTLBIpGx0aLh8f_aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A_VIAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAADTrqBlYv-5LM1MisyseqNW6ot1Tmlt31UxSUT6epkkWqnkY5FtE9Uytut9304AbtwVE-CtlrJZ0q6iJZFuqROy-KpvUnwzDVopJZH1U9Q-TtlVFsl1WyeIFgCnlwVyvkdFiFZEr357NfuT3s1kTgh6w7Cp6Z8Ek-I1Uz2IuZqu9x10twXxAsKqqp6VqOqp4oWqtkWR6NRd1-35Iq_Y9wzRzxpJBIySNVVEcxyOS6LZd6fO6FbpDhkuKU0UUMzYlY5yqrkct7sc3sVOZs4RSPoaBkEj0kcj3uzJf_ACeru1VXtA5Ks9puDUlZPTSU9er4ZHRuVsbbKrVVFt73yIf9VcD7tiHlt_I4mr0c0jg0gxOpp8GlnimlmRMytyua5yqi8b8lPVVgmPysiSPRZI5Gua90iI3Mrkfm3LfgvA-njQ6DEb_5Qx51Op3_AKl3mHe0rB6_EKajhgrmyTyNiaro22RVWyX947c-HYVo3j79KsLrJsDdSQxVETn6tGo1ER11cu_-2PuJlfUrFizVTFiecb75XNJcuXInxP4wAAzVwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAALCwACwAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFJX6SUlNiC4fSxVGIYg1Ec-npGI5Y0Xgr3KqNZ91J0W6rk4pjKNVcURmqV2DlMS0vfg8WvxrA8UpKRPiqGJHMxnzdkcqon2Oiw2upsSoYKyhlSammaj45EvZyc95Ouxct0xXVG0-fOP3hGm7TVPDE7tkAHF0AAAAVbJcoMD0po8ZxWsw-lhrGVFJ_1tdFkRi3siceKjKFVymiYpqneeS_AATAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAFNplij8F0XxPEYkvJTwOey_DNwT91QpPZHRsh0Ko6pVWSqr1dVVEzt7pHucu9V-lkOi0jwxmNYFX4dI7K2qhdFm6VVNy_ZbHzn2UaRfoqP0P0lVKLEqR7kp9auVsrFW9mqu5d6rbmipyNOxR4mirpt_dFUTPXhx-J5qVyrg1NM18piYj3_4-p1MEVTTywVDGyQytVj2O4OaqWVF-VjTxbEqPBMN2ip9yFmWNkcbbq5y7msanNeCIV2m8Ey4FW1tNiVbRSUlNLMxKd7Wo9yNVUzXat03HzCrqsUrPZhozpDUz1Fc-nrdqqnPXMtkerUWycETKifco3rdVGknURO0TjHrP-oaGjim_rKdPVtnz_HzOz6XjGkGI4PQLiFbg6LRMssyQ1KPlib1K3KiLbtspaQ4zR1GGU1dSya-GpRNTk4vVez1vwIMUxCgqdFaqufPG7DpaV71lVUyqxWr_APLHC6F0Vbguh-jc9eyRjWSvlexyb42vddt07N2_7mPr9VXpbc107xt8bxEz8ROfho2tPbvW8zHDVE4xvvtM4388xj5d_W4jNQRtmq6VEp7ojnxvzKy_NLJ-xDi-Pw0U-H0lNHtddXquzwtcjUVqJdz3O7GonbZV5IbGOviXBKpz3IrHRKjVTfmVeFvvY43FdG8YjqdG8bwlsc1fhzHRy0kkmTWRv4ojl3IqIqpv_wDRb0FUzrpsXas0TTxRM4jE74iZjG0_3v0ztTGNP4lEfqzj48594bi6X4pBphS6P4hhVJSvqUzxTrVucyRqccvub3bl3Lb_AMFVoPPHT-0DTyad7Y4onse9zlsjUTMqqpLh9TT6daYUtYkbqRmjsj0fDK5qyyTO3WsirZjcvHtUoaOinxLHvafR0iKtRK1EY1OLl95bffh9zS-o002uCKacVRG8eu_rPOMSyLebupsxXV-ma9p9OGf4nLu6vSesiwR-NQYVrMLazW3fUIyV0fWjVS1rb7Kt7F_g-I0-LYZTV1GrlgnYj2ZkstuSpzOC9mlRhGO4LS7fMtTiVG1IpKarkukKt3IrY1slrIm-1-an0WCSOWNHQvY-PgisVFT9jOs1TXEVZ2l9HrbdFmqbUU4mJ578vz77eyQAHdQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAK3GcCwvG4kjxagpqtrfh1saOVv0XihZAlTXVRPFTOJeVUxVGJhzUOg2jcNkbhMD2pwbIrpGp9nKqF_DSwQ0yU8MEUdOiZUiYxEaicrcLEwJXL1y599Uz7yjRbpo-2MKWn0WwOmmSSDC6Vio7OjUZ7qO5o3gi_OxcPY17Fa9qOau5UVLop6BxiimIxEO1dyuuc1TMtOHDaOB6Oip42q1btsnw_TkcVUYvJivtNqtHq2smoqGlpmSwwxSLE6se6yqqvT3rIi_C1UvZeR9BKjHdG8Hx7V_q-HwVTo_ge9tnN-jk3p4ljQ-BppmOHETHlEbT1w4aiLl2IxPKfPz9HCaaaM0mB4xg2L6Mq-kxqWtjhWFj1dtbHL7-ZFVVWzbqq8k39h0L8MocJ0ifWUejzXWbmdVxRKr1kcvvLuuqpZV7OPaXWD6N4Rg8iyYdQxRTKmVZVu99uWZyqtvlctzrqtR40U0zMzw-c8_wA8vdytaammZqmmPbo4Krw2ixTFm1NbofTvkVVzyyxrmctmrdVRtl4qm_iqFth-M1yJTs_Qp4IHOjjbG1it1LV3Kq7rWT6JuOnBTimI3iFyq7XXERVMzECAA9QAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABr16qlHKrVVFy8UWyjZYucvmu9SWeJJonRuVURyWunEj1EneZvBv4k4nbGcIzG5skXOXzXeo2SLnL5rvUaiTvM3g38RqJO8zeDfxGZ7jEdDZIucvmu9RskXOXzXeo1EneZvBv4jUSd5m8G_iMz3GI6GyRc5fNd6jZIucvmu9RqJO8zeDfxMLE9ONVKn1yfiMz3GI6M7JFzl813qNki5y-a71PORe9yfw9BkXvcn8PQZnuMR0etki5y-a71GyRc5fNd6nnIve5P4ehlInrwqpV-mT8Rme4xHRnZIucvmu9RskXOXzXep51a97l_h6DIve5P4egzPcYjo9bJFzl813qNki5y-a71PORe9yfw9BkXvcn8PQZnuMR0etki5y-a71GyRc5fNd6mEicvCqlX6ZPQzqJO8zeDfxGZ7jEdDZIucvmu9RskXOXzXeo1EneZvBv4jUSd5m8G_iMz3GI6GyRc5fNd6jZIucvmu9RqJO8zeDfxGok7zN4N_EZnuMR0Y2SLnL5rvUzRboVS7ls96JdVVbI5e1RqJO8zeDfxPcESQx5Uc529VVXcVVVuomduZEb8kgAIJAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGpiKuSL_by6yzsubhe26_yubZhzUd8SIv1QDj3VGk0dOqpRYXNI1vBJnIrlt9ETie45NJFoo1kiwtKtH-81HuyObk52ui5uXYdZqmdDfBBqmdDfBAOSfLpK5kuSmwljkemrXWPddvNfrwOloFVWKrkRHbronBFtvNjVM6G-CGWtRvwoifRAOaxJ2MtnzYW2gfDkamSoui5veut0_7d3zUilfpA1ZNTHhj2uc5WK9zmqxM25Nyb92-_M6nVs6G-A1TOhvggHGwz6Uo1sc9JheZY3Ksscq2R6JuRUXmv93EtVPpIkjnU9Hhmqa9VRqyuVz2WWyckd8Py4nW6pnQ3wQapnQ3wQDSwp0roWrUtY2dWNWRrFu1HdqIval-03zDWtb8KIn0QyAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAGptL-lo2l_S0hK6qw6WaZ8kddPCrnNcqNRLJl4W_u8C32l_Jo2l3JpTOw2dbqmI1Oa1kXlvvwJKakqIalrnVcksKNcisfzW1vsgFrtL-lo2l_S01aiPWwSR5lbnarbp2XS1yuZhk7I2MZiMzWN4NRv_ADz4AXe0u5NG0v6WlO7D6leGJVCfZPl6L4qWQE20v6WjaX8mlTNh8j6p07KyaNXf4oiWTdZLf3wJqOmlgkkdLUyT5kREzJbKiX9QLDaX9LRtL-lpCAJtpf0tG0v6WkIAm2l_S0bS_paQgCbaX9LRtL-lpCAJtpf0tG0v6WkIAm2l_S0bS_paQgCbaX9LRtL-lpCAJtpf0tG0v6WkIAm2l_S0bS_pT9yErf0xzLamsnjW6uday3VV_qAXG0u5NG0v6U_cqoqOoa1GyVssiatzHKqWVVVERF-2_wATH6c5I4UbUvbLHGketa1LuRFuBbbS7k0bS_paVcFFNFNG9a6eRrVVVY_ejtyp_wA_Y3gJtpf0p-42l3JpSphciNa1tdM1iLdGt3Je_wBbr9z1FQ1TKiNy4hM6JllVq_5Lfei_IC42l_S0bS_paQlc7D5tZmjrpo03-6ibrXRU49vFL_MC32l_Sg2l_JpUuw-XXTSRVckescrrNb9eK338fBE-pimoapkskktdI7MrkRtt1uz7px5AW-0u5NG0v6WlW2jmSZr1rp1RqouTsXhuU3gP_9k=",
  "height": 240,
  "mime_type": "image/jpeg",
  "width": 320
 }
}
```

Comment: from where are you getting this image ? is it a base64 encoded image ?

Comment: Check the first function:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15709515/save-base64-encoded-image-with-ajax-request-in-php

Comment: It's from a Google API..

Comment: @JesusRugama yes that looks like what im after thanks will let you know how it goes cheers

Comment: <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64,BASE64_ENCODED_DATA_HERE">

Answer (score 1):

you can try by using [file_put_contents](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-put-contents.php) function.simply:

```
$data="YOUR IMAGE DATA";
file_put_contents("test.jpg",$data);
```